# How can I replace all instances of a mispelled word during ispell?

Tags: ispell

I can be remarkably consistent with my misspellings some times; in these instances while running `ispell`, I'd like to be able to hit something like `C-u <correction number>` (for instance) to replace *all* instances of the mispelling at once.

Is there a way to tell ispell to not only replace the current word with a suggestion, but all future instances of that word with the same correction?

(As if I were to exit, then run `query-replace` and then hit `!` to replace all occurrences.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you switch on `ispell-query-replace-choices` by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` ispell uses `query-replace` if it finds multiple occurrences of the miss-spelled word after you choose a replacement.

After the first correction it will go to the next occurrence and query you with the menu of `query-replace-regexp`. The most important menu choices are:

- <kbd>!</kbd> replace all occurrences of the miss-spelled word with the chosen correction
- <kbd>y</kbd> replace this occurrence and go to the next occurrence
- <kbd>q</kbd> continue with the normal Ispell command loop

Comment: Is there a `customize-option`-free solution? Only using init-file?

Answer (score 1):

Using ispell-buffer, after replacing the first instance you can press "R" - which... yup, gives you query and replace. Not quite as convenient as what you're looking for but almost...